# onDraw in custom view is not executed anymore after onStop/onStart

Tags: android, kotlin, android-custom-view, ondraw

I'm using a custom view for drawing a slider (with two handles).

The custom view is extending ConstraintLayout, I'm setting setWillNotDraw() in the constructor and everything works fine - until the fragment containing the custom view is stopped and started again. Starting from this moment the onDraw method is not executed anymore after calling invalidate(). During debugging I checked the willNotDraw-Flag and it's still set to false.

- I'm using kotlinx
- I call setWillNotDraw(false) in init block
- I tested, if the containing fragment is created twice but everything there looks quite normal.
- I assured, that invalidate() is called.
- I assured, that willNotDraw() is set to false.
- The custom view is added to the fragment in the layout.xml
- `onCreate`, `onCreateView`, `onViewCreated` of fragment is only called once

**init block** in the custom view:

```
init {
  View.inflate(context, R.layout.layout_slider, this)
  setWillNotDraw(false)
}
```

**onDraw function** in the custom view:

```
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
  super.onDraw(canvas)

  Timber.d("onDraw")
}
```

After stopping and starting the containing fragment `onDraw` is not outputted anymore while everything else works fine.

Answer (score 0):

When I wrote my question I called `invalidate()` everywhere, where I wanted to redraw the view.

I changed the **init block** to

```
init {
  view = inflate(context, R.layout.layout_slider, this)

  setWillNotDraw(false)
}
```

and use `view?.invalidate()` instead of `invalidate()`.

Now everything works fine although I have no idea why it should make a difference.